# Шум перлина в юнити 2d, как убрать резкие перепады?

Tags: c#, unity3d, procedural-generation

Делаю генерацию мира в игре, вид сверху. Использую шум перлина в функции Generate():

```cs
    public void Generate()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            {
                float ny = y / size - Random.Range(0f, 2f);
                float nx = x / size - Random.Range(0f, 2f);
                humidityMap[y, x] = (Mathf.PerlinNoise(nx, ny));

                Debug.Log(humidityMap[y, x]);

                if (humidityMap[y, x] > 0)
                    biomesData[y, x] = Database.biomes[1];
                if (humidityMap[y, x] > 0.3)
                    biomesData[y, x] = Database.biomes[2];
                if (humidityMap[y, x] > 0.5)
                    biomesData[y, x] = Database.biomes[0];

                data[y, x] = biomesData[y, x].primaryBlock;
            }
        }
    }
```

Потом я заполняю массив биомов и массив тайлов на карте, затем рисую тайлы. Проблема в том что шум перлина генерирует слишком сильные перепады между значениями. Как это можно исправить?
*Если убрать строчку `Random.Range(0f, 2f)` при вычислении nx и ny то значения получаются одинаковыми и шум перлина возвращает одинаковые значения*.
Результат генерации прикреплён

[image: Результат генерации]

Comment: Мне кажется для генерации мира можно использовать алгоритм из игры "Жизнь" (гуглится). Просто остановиться на каком-то шаге алгоритма, прекратить "игру" и будет готовый мир :)

Comment: @AntonNikolaev я использую шум перлина для генерации карты влажности и температуры, то есть мне нужен именно рандомный шум, зависящий от предыдущих значений, а по алгоритму из игры жизнь карта будет получатся без плавных переходов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема тут: `y / size` - целочисленное деление. Оно всегда выдаст ноль. Сделайте его вещественным (`(float)y / size`) и уберите `Random.Range`.

Чтобы сделать шум случайным вне циклов вычислите

```
float dy = Random.Range(0f, 1000f);
float dx = Random.Range(0f, 1000f);
```

В цикле

```
float ny = (float)y / size + dy;
float nx = (float)x / size + dx;
```

Comment: Да, стало лучше, но результат всегда одинаковый, как его можно сделать полностью случайным а не псевдослучайным?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое